# Printing elements of a list splitted on new lines every N items

Tags: python, list, printing, split

I need to print my lists on multiple lines every N element without splitting the original list in smaller lists.

For example, with N = 3

Given this:

`MY_LIST = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']`

I want python to print THIS:

```
A B C

D E F
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.islice` and a generator function:

```
>>> import math
>>> from itertools import islice
def solve(lis, n):                                              
    it = iter(lis)
    le = float(len(lis))
    for _ in xrange(int(math.ceil(le/n))):
        yield " ".join(islice(it, n))

>>> for x in solve([ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 3):
...     print x
...     
A B C
D E F
```

Using the py3.x's `print` function:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(*solve([ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 3), sep='\n')
A B C
D E F
>>> print(*solve([ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 3), sep='\n')
A B C
D E F
G
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`'\n'.join([' '.join(i) for i in zip(*[iter(MY_LIST)]*N)])`

Example:

```
>>> MY_LIST = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
>>> N=3
>>> '\n'.join([' '.join(i) for i in zip(*[iter(MY_LIST)]*N)])
'A B C\nD E F'
```

Comment: Watch out for when `len(MY_LIST) %3 != 0`...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for x in (MY_LIST[i:i + N] for i in xrange(0, len(MY_LIST), N)):
...    print " ".join(x)
A B C
D E F
```